# Set background color to a texture

Tags: opengl, graphics, colors, background

So in openGL when I call glClearColor() is there a way to set the background color to a texture instead of setting it just to a static color? Or is there another method which can do that besides glClearColor()?

Comment: you want to set background with texture image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot clear the screen to a texture. You can:

- Draw a textured quad the size of the screen.
- [Blit a texture from an FBO](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Framebuffer_Blitting) onto the screen.

Either one will work.